# If the menu item is visible

Tags: c#, menuitem

I want to see if this: http://spunit.tk/x/Untitled-1_2.png is visible or not. I've tried this:

```
if ((menuStrip1.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems["itmAdd"].Visible == true)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: How does it not work? Help us help you.

Comment: It doesn't go into the if (when it is visible). You mean that I should try without the " == true". I tried to remove it, but it still doesn't go into the if. No errors though.

Comment: What do you mean with _"It doesn't go into the if"_? Show us more code please...

Comment: Ok. This is my code: http://spunit.tk/x/325431.png .
separator1 is never displayed.

Comment: Ok, but when is this code invoked? Did you put a breakpoint over it and stepped to see what's happening? You could write it shorter `(menuStrip1.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems["separator1"].Visible = (menuStrip1.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems["itmAdd2"].Visible`. Are you sure about names?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a real noob, so I've not yet learned how to do that, sorry =(. And yes, I'm sure about the names, and I know they are bad. I just cant understand what I do wrong... And thanks for all your help, much appreciated.

Comment: This is how my code looks now http://spunit.tk/x/Untitled-2.png

Comment: Hmmm... Replacing Visible with Enabled seems to work... But this is not what I want to check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with you my friend. I suppose this is a bug or something.
So i replaced .visible with .enable property and did my job. But i think another good solution would be to create and add these items when u need and remove them when u don't.